# Central limit theorem for asymptotically i.i.d. random variables

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics, iid

I observe a sequence of r.v. $X_1, X_2, \dots$ where each $X_i$ is a function of the sample size $n$.

When $n \rightarrow \infty$ I have the following result: $X_1 \rightarrow^d E_1, X_2 \rightarrow^d E_2, \dots$ where $E_i$ are i.i.d random variable with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2 < \infty$ and same density $f_E$. Moreover,

- $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E(X_i) = \mu$$
- $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}V(X_i) = \sigma^2$$
- $$\textrm{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = O(n^{-1})$$

Denote $\bar X_n = n^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$, can I claim that (Linderberg-Levy CLT type)

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_{n}-\mu\right) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{2}\right) ? 
$$

In other words:  if the dependence of the elements of the summation fades **only asymptotically**, does the CLT still holds?

Comment: "X_1 converges in distribution to E_1" doesn't make sense as X_1 isn't a sequence, it's a single random variable. Same thing for X_2, X_3, etc. The question doesn't make sense as it stands.

Comment: @Paul Strictly speaking you are correct, but let's help the new contributor,: they obviously imply that each $X_i$ is a function of $n$, hence the convergence result. Standard example: the $X$'s are in reality residuals from a regression with i.i.d. errors. Then each residual converges to the corresponding true error, and the question acquires meaning and substance: if dependence of the elements of the sum vanish only asymptotically, does the CLT still holds? Under perhaps additional conditions?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos thank you! It is indeed my question.

Comment: I don't find the missing information obvious. The question cannot accept answers until it is edited to make sense.

Now it seems to be OK so I voted to reopen.

Comment: Now that the question makes sense, the problem here is that convergence in distribution is too weak and provides no insurance against correlations between the X_i. The condition that the E_i are independent does not help. In fact, the X_i could all be the exact same variable and still converge in distribution to "iid E_i". You will need a stronger form of convergence to get the X_i to become "more independent" as n increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that convergence in distribution is too weak and provides no insurance against correlations between the $X_i$. The condition that the $E_i$ are independent does not help. In fact, the $X_i$ could all be the exact same variable and still converge in distribution to the iid $E_i$. You will need a stronger form of convergence to get the $X_i$ to become less dependent as $n$ increases - convergence in probability at minimum, or perhaps something stronger.

The condition of $O(n^{-1})$ decaying correlation unfortunately doesn't help either, as the central limit theorem [does not hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330725/central-limit-theorem-for-uncorrelated-rv-counter-example) on merely uncorrelated random variables.

For what it's worth, some central limit theorems work under different assumptions than Lindeberg-Lévy, such as the [martingale CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_central_limit_theorem).